# Edit listView value

Tags: java, android, listview, android-edittext, edit

I have 3 activities, A, B and C.The flow of activity is from A to B then C. From C, all the images and value will be returned to B then A.  All the returned value and image will be loaded in `listView` A.

The `listView` is clickable and once it is clicked, it will `intent` to B to do some edition. But the problem now is when I edit the text value in B and return to A, I get a new list instead of updating the old one.
What's wrong here ? Anyone can help?

**Activity C**

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.image_fit_screen);
        selectImage();
        b = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        t = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText38);
        cancel=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button15);
        ok=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button16);

        cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {  // return to B
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {
                Intent returnIntent=new Intent();
                text=t.getText().toString();
                b.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                b.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                        View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
                b.layout(0, 0, b.getMeasuredWidth(), b.getMeasuredHeight());
                b.buildDrawingCache(true);
                returnIntent.putExtra("text", text);
                if (b.getDrawingCache() != null) {
                    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(b.getDrawingCache());
                    if (bitmap == null) {
                        Log.e("TAG", "getDrawingCache() == null");
                    }
                    Global.img = bitmap;
                }
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
```

**Activity B**

```
    ImageButton imageButton;
    ImageView viewImage;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.project);
        txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText36);
        txt1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView57);
        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button17);
        addListenerOnButton();
        viewImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

        if(getIntent().getExtras()!=null) { //if  has value pass from A
            final String Amount = getIntent().getExtras().getString("result");
            final String description1 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("description");

            txt1.setText(description1);
            txt.setText(Amount);
        }

                b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  // return to A
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                        a = "Project";
                        text = txt.getText().toString(); // amount
                        returnIntent.putExtra("text", text);
                        returnIntent.putExtra("a", a);
                        returnIntent.putExtra("c", c);
                        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
                        finish();
                    }
                });
                viewImage.setImageBitmap(Global.img);

                }



    public void addListenerOnButton() {
         imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
         imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Global.img=null;
                Intent i = new Intent(B.this,C.class);
                startActivityForResult(i, PROJECT_REQUEST_CODE);
            }

        });

    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if(requestCode==PROJECT_REQUEST_CODE) { // receive fom C
            if(data!=null&&data.hasExtra("text")) {
                c = data.getStringExtra("text");
                txt1.setText(c);
                viewImage.setImageBitmap(Global.img);  // image from C can be shown here
            }


        }
        else if (requestCode==CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE)
        {

        }
    }

}
```

**Activity A**

```
public class Claims1 extends Fragment {

    ListView listV;
    String description;
    String result="";
    String name;
    long as=0;
    TextView c;
    ImageView v;
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ArrayList<String> m_listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    String Text;

  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        View claims = inflater.inflate(R.layout.receipt_text, container, false);
        v=(ImageView)claims.findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
        listV = (ListView) claims.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        android.support.v7.app.ActionBar myActionBar = ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
        myActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(myActionBar.getThemedContext());
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.create);


        adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.claims,R.id.textView1,m_listItems);

        android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams layoutParams = new android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams(
                android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.RIGHT
                | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);  // for icon in action bar
        layoutParams.rightMargin = 40;
        imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        myActionBar.setCustomView(imageView);

        listV.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
              if(name.equals("Project")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Claims1.this.getActivity(), B.class);
                    intent.putExtra("bitmap",true);
                    intent.putExtra("name",name);
                    intent.putExtra("result",result);
                    startActivityForResult(intent,0);
                }

            }
        });
        return claims;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.create1:
                AlertDialogRadio();
                return true;
        }
        return (super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
    }


    public void AlertDialogRadio() {
        final CharSequence[] ClaimsModel = {"B", "Petrol"};

        AlertDialog.Builder alt_bld = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        alt_bld.setTitle("Select a Class");
        alt_bld.setSingleChoiceItems(ClaimsModel, -1, new DialogInterface
                .OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                if (item == 0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),B.class);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                } else if (item == 1) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Petrol.class);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                } 
                dialog.dismiss();

            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = alt_bld.create();
        alert.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        switch (requestCode) {
                case 0:
                    result = data.getStringExtra("text");
                    name = data.getStringExtra("a");
                    description = data.getStringExtra("c");
                    as = Long.parseLong(result);
                    Log.d("FIRST", "result:"+result);
                    Text="  "+name+"                                  "+"RM"+result+"";
                    m_listItems.add(Text);
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    listV.setAdapter(adapter);

                    break;

                case 1:
                    result = data.getStringExtra("text");
                    name = data.getStringExtra("a");
                    description = data.getStringExtra("c");
                    if (Global.img != null) {
                        v.setImageBitmap(Global.img);
                    }
                    as = Long.parseLong(result);
                    c.setText("                            " + name + "------" + "RM " + result);
                    break;
        }

    }
```

**Edited**

Add a global variable in A - `private int mClickedPosition`;
Add `mClickedPosition = position;` in OnItemClick

then

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    switch (requestCode) {
            case 0:
                result = data.getStringExtra("text");
                name = data.getStringExtra("a");
                description = data.getStringExtra("c");
                as = Long.parseLong(result);
                Log.d("FIRST", "result:"+result);
                Text="  "+name+"                                  "+"RM"+result+"";
                m_listItems.set(mClickedPosition,Text);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                listV.setAdapter(adapter);

                break;
```

> 11-16 18:15:54.751  23044-23044/com.example.project.project
>   E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.project.project, PID: 23044
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=android:fragment:0, request=0, result=-1, data=Intent {
>   (has extras) }} to activity
>   {com.example.project.project/com.example.project.project.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3681)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3724)

```
 m_listItems.set(mClickedPosition,Text);
```

Comment: Your description seems to be misleading. From class A you go to B not to C. Quoting you: _'The flow of activity is from A to C,'_ Please read thourgh your description again, and edit any misleading statements.

Comment: provide more code with adapter for listview

Comment: New list ? means what? Dont you want the list to be updated? Explain your issue so that we can help you

Comment: @VishalPatel I have posted all my code in Activity A

Comment: @John: I think need to remove `finish();` from `A` when starting Activity `B`

Comment: What is that `return claims;` in Activity A?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK where you see the `finish()` from A

Comment: @John: on Ok button click here : `setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);finish();`

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK if I remove `finish()` , it will not going back to A

Comment: I think your dataset in the adapter is not updating.In activity A try adding adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); before listV.setAdapter(adapter);

Comment: adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  put onResume method

Comment: show please  line how you create `adapter`? thx

Comment: @VishalPatel where should I add in `onResume()`

Comment: It would be a good idea to post the whole Activity classes, and also a better indenting would help a lot.

Comment: How do you init `adapter`? Please paste code like this: `adapter = new ArrayAdapter(.....`

Comment: @walkmn what should write inside the bracket?

Comment: @John   in your activity dear

Comment: Can someone help me ? Why I cannot add new list [now](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33741464/how-to-update-and-add-a-new-list-in-listview/33741634?noredirect=1#comment55252391_33741634) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try edit your code like this:

```
case 0:
    result = data.getStringExtra("text");
    name = data.getStringExtra("a");
    description = data.getStringExtra("c");
    as = Long.parseLong(result);
    Log.d("FIRST", "result:"+result);
    Text="  "+name+"                                  "+"RM"+result+"";
    if (m_listItems.size() == 0) {
        m_listItems.add(Text);
    } else {
        m_listItems.set(mClickedPosition,Text);
    }
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    listV.setAdapter(adapter);

    break;
```

Comment: Wait... Now i only able to update the list ..how to add new list

Comment: please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33741464/how-to-update-and-add-a-new-list-in-listview/33741634#33741634

Answer (score 2):

in your activity A onActivityResult method when you return from activity B after editing  you are   adding new item into arraylist using this code `m_listItems.add(Text)`;

instead of adding new item you update the array list using this code

```
m_listItems.set(position Text);
```

Comment: `m_listItems.set(position Text);` or `m_listItems.set(position,Text);`

Comment: @John if you want to update adapter update array list not add new item in array list

Comment: Do I need to create position as global variable?

Comment: this is  position where you click on activity A listview you can send this position using intent into B when you click on activity A listView and send back while you come back from activity B to A .

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent(Claims1.this.getActivity(), B.class); send position in this intent and receive it on crate of B and then send back while we came back in A and inside A onactivityResult method you will be able to get postion

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95229/discussion-between-vishal-jangid-and-john).

Comment: Thanks for your help. Highly appreciated