# How to update and add a new list in listView?

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, android-listview

In my Activity A, it has one icon `button` and one `listView`. The icon `button` is used to `intent` to B and C while the `listView` is used to `intent` B to do some edit.

I have 3 activities, A, B and C.The flow of activity is from A to B then C. From C, all the images and value will be returned to B then A. All the returned value and image will be loaded in `listView` A.

Now what I trying to achieve is load all value which is get from C and B to A. Next, the list can be updated when listView is clicked.

**Activity C**

```
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.image_fit_screen);
        selectImage();
        b = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
        t = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText38);
        cancel=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button15);
        ok=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button16);

        cancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                finish();
            }
        });

        ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {  // return to B
            public void onClick(View arg0)
            {
                Intent returnIntent=new Intent();
                text=t.getText().toString();
                b.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                b.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED),
                        View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
                b.layout(0, 0, b.getMeasuredWidth(), b.getMeasuredHeight());
                b.buildDrawingCache(true);
                returnIntent.putExtra("text", text);
                if (b.getDrawingCache() != null) {
                    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(b.getDrawingCache());
                    if (bitmap == null) {
                        Log.e("TAG", "getDrawingCache() == null");
                    }
                    Global.img = bitmap;
                }
                setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
```

**Activity B**

```
    ImageButton imageButton;
    ImageView viewImage;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.project);
        txt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText36);
        txt1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView57);
        Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button17);
        addListenerOnButton();
        viewImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);

        if(getIntent().getExtras()!=null) { //if  has value pass from A
            final String Amount = getIntent().getExtras().getString("result");
            final String description1 = getIntent().getExtras().getString("description");

            txt1.setText(description1);
            txt.setText(Amount);
        }

                b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  // return to A
                    public void onClick(View arg0) {
                        Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
                        a = "Project";
                        text = txt.getText().toString(); // amount
                        returnIntent.putExtra("text", text);
                        returnIntent.putExtra("a", a);
                        returnIntent.putExtra("c", c);
                        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, returnIntent);
                        finish();
                    }
                });
                viewImage.setImageBitmap(Global.img);

                }



    public void addListenerOnButton() {
         imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
         imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                Global.img=null;
                Intent i = new Intent(B.this,C.class);
                startActivityForResult(i, PROJECT_REQUEST_CODE);
            }

        });

    }

    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode,int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        if(requestCode==PROJECT_REQUEST_CODE) { // receive fom C
            if(data!=null&&data.hasExtra("text")) {
                c = data.getStringExtra("text");
                txt1.setText(c);
                viewImage.setImageBitmap(Global.img);  // image from C can be shown here
            }


        }
        else if (requestCode==CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE)
        {

        }
    }

}
```

**Activity A**

```
public class Claims1 extends Fragment {
    private int mClickedPosition;
    ListView listV;
    TextView c;
    ImageView v;
  ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    ArrayList<String> m_listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    String Text;

  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
        View claims = inflater.inflate(R.layout.receipt_text, container, false);
        v=(ImageView)claims.findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
        listV = (ListView) claims.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        android.support.v7.app.ActionBar myActionBar = ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
        myActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        ImageView imageView = new ImageView(myActionBar.getThemedContext());
        imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
        imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.create);


        adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.claims,R.id.textView1,m_listItems);

        android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams layoutParams = new android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams(
                android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.RIGHT
                | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);  // for icon in action bar
        layoutParams.rightMargin = 40;
        imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        myActionBar.setCustomView(imageView);

        listV.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        mClickedPosition = position;
              public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
              if(name.equals("Project")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(Claims1.this.getActivity(), B.class);
                    intent.putExtra("bitmap",true);
                    intent.putExtra("name",name);
                    intent.putExtra("result",result);
                    startActivityForResult(intent,0);
                }

            }
        });
        return claims;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.create1: // icon is clicked
                AlertDialogRadio();
                return true;
        }
        return (super.onOptionsItemSelected(item));
    }


    public void AlertDialogRadio() {
        final CharSequence[] ClaimsModel = {"B", "Petrol"};

        AlertDialog.Builder alt_bld = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        alt_bld.setTitle("Select a Class");
        alt_bld.setSingleChoiceItems(ClaimsModel, -1, new DialogInterface
                .OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                if (item == 0) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),B.class);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
                } else if (item == 1) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), Petrol.class);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                } 
                dialog.dismiss();

            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = alt_bld.create();
        alert.show();
    }

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    switch (requestCode) {
        case 0:
            result = data.getStringExtra("text");
            name = data.getStringExtra("a");
            description = data.getStringExtra("c");
            as = Long.parseLong(result);
            Log.d("FIRST", "result:"+result);
            Text="  "+name+"                                  "+"RM"+result+"";
            if (m_listItems.size() == 0) {
                m_listItems.add(Text);
            } else {
                m_listItems.set(mClickedPosition,Text);
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            listV.setAdapter(adapter);

            break;
         }
      }
```

**But now, when I click the icon `button` to intent class B and C and return values from C and B to A, it only update the `listView` instead of create a new one. Why would this happen ?**

Comment: check my answer below.  Added a method called setAdapter(); make sure to replace your onCreateView() and onActivityResult() and add the setAdapter()

Comment: What exactly isn't resolvable?  Copy and paste the line for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check my edit

```
public class Claims1 extends Fragment {
private int mClickedPosition;
ListView listV;
TextView c;
ImageView v;
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
ArrayList<String> m_listItems = new ArrayList<String>();
String Text;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    View claims = inflater.inflate(R.layout.receipt_text, container, false);
    v=(ImageView)claims.findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
    listV = (ListView) claims.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    android.support.v7.app.ActionBar myActionBar = ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar();
    myActionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(myActionBar.getThemedContext());
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER);
    imageView.setImageResource(R.mipmap.create);

    android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams layoutParams = new android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams(
            android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            android.support.v7.app.ActionBar.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.RIGHT
            | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);  // for icon in action bar
    layoutParams.rightMargin = 40;
    imageView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    myActionBar.setCustomView(imageView);

    setMyAdapter();
    return claims;
}

public void setMyAdapter() {
    adapter=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),R.layout.claims,R.id.textView1,m_listItems);
    listV.setAdapter(adapter);

    listV.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
          public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
          mClickedPosition = position;
          if(name.equals("Project")) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Claims1.this.getActivity(), B.class);
                intent.putExtra("bitmap",true);
                intent.putExtra("name",name);
                intent.putExtra("result",result);
                startActivityForResult(intent,0);
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    switch (requestCode) {
    case 0:
        result = data.getStringExtra("text");
        name = data.getStringExtra("a");
        description = data.getStringExtra("c");
        as = Long.parseLong(result);
        Log.d("FIRST", "result:" + result);
        Text = "  " + name + "                                  " + "RM" + result + "";
        m_listItems.clear();
        if (m_listItems.size() == 0) {
            m_listItems.add(Text);
        } else {
            m_listItems.set(mClickedPosition, Text);
        }
        setMyAdapter();
        break;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the return value still updating the old one instead of create a new list

Comment: @John hmm if you want a new list that should do the trick so is the text changing atleast?   The way you are doing this will make it difficult to change much more than the text.

Comment: I only get the text changing...I want to add new list also

Comment: I'm lost it basically is a new list everything was cleared

Comment: Maybe clear your adapter /// adapter.clear();  and see if you can add the items into the adapter instead of the list.  adapter.add(Text);  Sorry if that doesn't help

Comment: This is my previous [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33731688/edit-listview-value). Before this, it only can add new list. After get the solution, now it cannot add new list :)

Comment: I think I have a fix one minute I'm doing a big edit

Comment: Moved it to the right spot check where its placed now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95270/discussion-between-john-and-jasz).